# Add Section to URL Without Adding Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have a MVC application with a few views designed to manage office details. The views come up fine via localhost/MyApp/MyView1, but I would like the URL to also have a section for OfficeMgr. For example: localhost/MyApp/OfficeMgr/MyView1.

I do not want to have a controller named OfficeMgr. I would just like the URL to have an extra section.

How can I add the OfficeMgr section to the URL?

Comment: you can add areas in your project or just add the specific routes to redirect to your controller

Comment: I will look into Areas, that seems promising.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify any prefix attribute to your route:

The file `App_Start\RouteConfig.cs` is responsible for route configuration in your application. You can add or change the default route to provide the aditional section, for exemple:

```
 routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{area}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { area = "OfficeMgr", controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Then your url will look like: `http://myserver/OfficeMgr/Home/Index`

You should take a look here, for more Asp.net MVC Route information:

- [Controllers and Routing](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/controllers-and-routing)

If you need to split your application in defined Areas, you should use MVC Areas for this:

1. [Walkthrough: Organizing an ASP.NET MVC Application using Areas](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee671793%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)
2. [Using areas in ASP.NET MVC to organize a project](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/601504/Using-areas-in-ASP-NET-MVC-to-organize-a-project)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The OfficeMgr section would just be for a couple of views, not all of them.

Comment: Then you should implement Areas, that will segment the application based on some logic like Administration, Office, Finantial for exemple.